# using a dynamic class for the body tag

Tags: symfony, twig

in my `base.html.twig` my `body` looks like this:

```
<body>
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}
    {% block body %}

    {% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/remodal.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/script.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Since my files `homepage.html.twig` and `subpage.html.twig` `extend` the file `base.html.twig`, I would like to pass a class to the `body` tag.

E.g. in my file `homepage.html.twig` I want it to be `<body class="home">` and in my `subpage.html.twig` file I want it to be `<body class="subpage">`.

Is it possible to simply pass a variable or something like that or would it be necessary to use a `block` for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that the easiest way is to simply define a `block` like this:

`<body class="{% block body_class %}sub_page{% endblock %}">`

Then **only** in `homepage.html.twig` using:

`{% block body_class %}homepage{% endblock %}`